# I am trying to generate Choropleth Maps , Nothings Shows on screen

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I am trying to generate a choropleth map of india with some data , everything seems to work fine, i cleaned the data and made a proper Pandas Dataframe, but somehow its still blank. the geojson _id matches with the dataframe yet no resolve.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np


india_map = json.load(open('INDIA_STATES.json','r'))
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
df_s = pd.DataFrame({'Stats':df['Unnamed: 7'][3:38]},)
#print(df_s)
df = pd.concat([df['Unnamed: 1'][3:38],df_s],axis=1,ignore_index=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:"State",df.columns[1]:"Stat"})
#print(df)
state_id_json = []
state_name_json = []

for st in india_map['features']:
    state_name_json.append(st['properties']['STATE'])
    state_id_json.append(st['_id'])

state_name_json = list(map(lambda x:x.upper(),state_name_json))
df['State'] = list(map(lambda x:x.upper(),df['State']))
state_id = pd.DataFrame({"State":state_name_json,"_id":state_id_json}).sort_values(by=['State'])
#print(state_id,df)
df = pd.merge(df,state_id,on='State')
print(df)

fig = px.choropleth(df,geojson=india_map,locations='_id',color='Stat',scope= 'asia')
fig.show()
```

I get this in Terminal :

```
                          State      Stat      _id
0   ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS     356.0        8
1                ANDHRA PRADESH   76210.0        9
2             ARUNACHAL PRADESH    1098.0       10
3                         ASSAM   26656.0       11
4                         BIHAR   82999.0  row_112
5                    CHANDIGARH     901.0       35
6                    CHANDIGARH     901.0       13
7                  CHHATTISGARH   20834.0  row_251
8                 DAMAN AND DIU     158.0       34
9                         DELHI   13851.0       16
10                          GOA    1348.0       17
11                      GUJARAT   50671.0       18
12                      HARYANA   21145.0       19
13             HIMACHAL PRADESH    6078.0       20
14            JAMMU AND KASHMIR   10144.0        7
15                    JHARKHAND   26946.0  row_267
16                    KARNATAKA   52851.0       21
17                       KERALA   31841.0       22
18                  LAKSHADWEEP      61.0       23
19               MADHYA PRADESH   60348.0  row_250
20                  MAHARASHTRA   96879.0       25
21                      MANIPUR    2294.0       26
22                    MEGHALAYA    2319.0       27
23                      MIZORAM     889.0       28
24                     NAGALAND    1990.0       29
25                       ODISHA   36805.0       30
26                   PUDUCHERRY     974.0       37
27                       PUNJAB   24359.0        1
28                    RAJASTHAN   56507.0        2
29                       SIKKIM     541.0        3
30                   TAMIL NADU   62406.0        4
31                      TRIPURA    3199.0        5
32                UTTAR PRADESH  166198.0       31
33                  WEST BENGAL   80176.0       32
```

Plotly Result:

*Empty Map with no data*
[image: Empty Map with no data]

Answer (score 0):

Since no geojson was provided, I used Json retrieved from the web and created the code with the data you provided. geojson was not provided, so I may not be certain, but I think it was probably due to a missing `featureidkey` setting. In my example, I have associated the state name with `NAME_1` in geojson. Some of the state names do not match, so I adapted them to geojson.

**Note:**
Some states are missing because the state name in the user data does not match `NAME_1` in geojson. Please replace it with your data.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import plotly.express as px

# https://github.com/Subhash9325/GeoJson-Data-of-Indian-States/blob/master/Indian_States
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Subhash9325/GeoJson-Data-of-Indian-States/master/Indian_States'

with urlopen(url) as response:
    india_map = json.load(response)

data = '''
                       State      Stat      _id
0   "ANDAMAN AND NICOBAR ISLANDS"     356.0        8
1                "ANDHRA PRADESH"   76210.0        9
2             "ARUNACHAL PRADESH"    1098.0       10
3                         ASSAM   26656.0       11
4                         BIHAR   82999.0  row_112
5                    CHANDIGARH     901.0       35
6                    CHANDIGARH     901.0       13
7                  CHHATTISGARH   20834.0  row_251
8                 "DAMAN AND DIU"     158.0       34
9                         DELHI   13851.0       16
10                          GOA    1348.0       17
11                      GUJARAT   50671.0       18
12                      HARYANA   21145.0       19
13             "HIMACHAL PRADESH"    6078.0       20
14            "JAMMU AND KASHMIR"   10144.0        7
15                    JHARKHAND   26946.0  row_267
16                    KARNATAKA   52851.0       21
17                       KERALA   31841.0       22
18                  LAKSHADWEEP      61.0       23
19               "MADHYA PRADESH"   60348.0  row_250
20                  MAHARASHTRA   96879.0       25
21                      MANIPUR    2294.0       26
22                    MEGHALAYA    2319.0       27
23                      MIZORAM     889.0       28
24                     NAGALAND    1990.0       29
25                       ODISHA   36805.0       30
26                   PUDUCHERRY     974.0       37
27                       PUNJAB   24359.0        1
28                    RAJASTHAN   56507.0        2
29                       SIKKIM     541.0        3
30                   "TAMIL NADU"   62406.0        4
31                      TRIPURA    3199.0        5
32                "UTTAR PRADESH"  166198.0       31
33                  "WEST BENGAL"   80176.0       32
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df['State'] = df['State'].str.title()
df['State'] = df['State'].str.replace(' And ', ' and ') 
df.loc[0, 'State'] = 'Andaman and Nicobar'

fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    geojson=india_map,
                    locations='State',
                    color='Stat',
                    featureidkey="properties.NAME_1",
                    scope='asia')

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)

fig.update_layout(autosize=False,
                  width=1000,
                  height=600
                 )
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Problem was with the json itself.